# Undefined CLR namespace

Tags: wpf

I have the following:

[image: Error! Error!]

The error says **The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace '{0}' that is not included in the assembly.**

I've build and rebuild but nothing happens. I'm sure this must work, because a WPF demo app that I downloaded has everything the same. What's going on?

Comment: What’s going on is that the designer is a little rough around the edges and has a bunch of issues like that. In other words, it’s not you, it’s Visual Studio.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming your ViewModel folder isn't empty (or there actually is a type with `BlooblieBlablie.ViewModel` as its namespace), and `BlooblieBlablie` is the assembly name, the following should work:

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:BlooblieBlablie.ViewModel;assembly=BlooblieBlablie"
```

Comment: The assembly part is not necessary as the namespace is in the same assembly as the XAML file.

Comment: Ah, I got the idea because of what you said: "or there actually is a type with BlooblieBlablie.ViewModel as its namespace". This is what the problem was - The class in the ViewModel folder actually needed an AssemblyName that was AssemblyName.ViewModel. <i>Then</i> it should work

Comment: @Daniel: Ah, didn't know that, to be honest. I started out specifying the assembly part from the beginning, and kept on doing it ever since.

Answer (score 9):

I had similar problem when project's solution platform was set to x64. When I changed it to x86 problem went away.

Here is some explanation:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/6379d330-f382-4b4d-a690-e89326ab4c72

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it by not having my project in a path with hash-mark.

E.g D:#Temp had to be D:\Temp

I guess there's someone at Microsoft having missed an EscapedCodeBase in conjunction with the URI.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message given to me. But the underlying problem was different. I moved my MainWindow.xaml to a different folder, and I forgot to update my App.xaml StartupUri. I then updated my StartupUri in my App.xaml and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Also verify the "BuildAction" of the .xaml files (see file properties).
Should be "Page". 
After I moved files and renamed the namespace this setting changed somehow to "CodeAnalysisDictionary". This also leeds to this error.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I can see, that namespace simply doesn't exist ;-) In your ViewModel folder is no file. And without file, there is no namespace. Namespaces are not defined by folder structure but inside source files.

Comment: I made this screenshot to be a little bit easier to look at. In my real application I do have something in my ViewModel folder, namely a class called ViewModel.cs.

Comment: And you are sure the namespace in that file reads `BlooblieBlablie.ViewModel`?

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your screenshot, your `ViewModel` folder seems to be empty. If there are no classes in the namespace `BlooblieBlablie.ViewModel`, the namespace does not exist yet.

Comment: I made this screenshot to be a little bit easier to look at. In my real application I do have something in my ViewModel folder, namely a class called ViewModel.cs.

Answer (score 1):

I got this after Windows 7 computer crash when I was in solution in Visual Studio 2008.  It seems to have blanked out the start-up configuration.  I reset this and then it could find the name-space.  This is one cause - probably not the major one - but just in case you have same.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, mine was self inflicted due to copying and pasting code from another source into my project and renaming objects as I went without building first.

So, this means Visual Studio or the compiler do not pick up on incorrect references (eg, in my code I had this:

```
MyObect mo = new MyObect();
```

When I copied the code over, I corrected the spelling of  `MyObect` to `MyObject` but, Visual Studio has still referencing MyObect and didn't give any warnings about this. And this was code was part of a .XAML file and as such, I was not only getting the error message you were, but also .g.cs errors too. All of them pointing to the *incorrect* reasons.

This was also occuring in the ResourceDictionary (within my datatemplate declarations for all my VM binding)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today after I had to rename class (and file with it) in the namespace. So I was able to solve it by deleting **.sln** file, then run **.csproj** and recreate **.sln** file.